# Using wildcard for columns in select query in mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I want to select those columns starting with string "time",however i  dont want to use * anyways.
   select "columns starting with string time" from mytable limit 10;

how can i get this done.

Comment: Build a dynamic sql statement using information_schema.columns to pick the columns you are interested in.

Comment: Perhaps those columns are "an array splayed across columns"?  If so, perhaps it is poor schema design?  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.